# XPath for specific site in Google Sheets

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to import table shows in below link:
https://www.codal.ir/ReportList.aspx?search&LetterType=6&AuditorRef=-1&PageNumber=1&Audited&NotAudited&IsNotAudited=false&Childs=false&Mains&Publisher=false&CompanyState=0&Category=1&CompanyType=1&Consolidatable&NotConsolidatable=false

it is not possible by importhtml, and I have tried some xpaths by importxml but failed.

Answer (score 3):

this is not an issue of XPath. the website you are trying to scrape is dependant on JavaScript. Google Sheets does not support import of JS elements. your only option is to find the same data you need on some other website. you can test the JS dependency simply by disabling it for a given site and what's left of it can be scraped - in your case, nothing:

[image: 0]

Comment: thanks. but in its previous version I was able to import.

Comment: @MortezaJafari I am not aware of past. as of now, this is the only answer to your issue.